# cannot subscript a value of type pfobject

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am receiving an error of "Cannot subscript a value of type "PFObject".For the following code:

```
self.Question = objectHolder["Question"] as! String!
```

anyone know how to fix it or any advice?
I am using Xcode 7 and Querying Parse.

full function

```
func CallData(){
    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "QuestionsandAnswers")
   query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Parse Object id is here") {
        (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.Question = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Question") as! String
            self.Answers = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Answers") as! Array
            self.Answer = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Answer") as! String

            if(self.Answers.count > 0){
                self.QuestionLabel.text = self.Question




            }
```

Comment: Nevermind the fix I had in mind did not work and it placed more errors anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: how is `objectHolder` defined?

Comment: (ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment that ObjectHolder is defined as:

```
(ObjectHolder : PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

This means that ObjectHolder is not an array but already a single PFObject. Assuming that you typed the key ("Question") correctly and you're querying for the right object, you can get what you're looking for by using:

```
self.Question = ObjectHolder.valueForKey("Question") as! String
```

The way you had originally written it would only work if you were pulling a dictionary from Parse. If you were pulling an array you could subscript it but not with the key; you would need to find it by the index (i.e. `ObjectHolder[0].valueForKey("Question") as! String`)

^side note: Parse does not let you store dictionaries that you write in any language, only arrays.

Comment: now I get an error of "cannot invoke 'getObjectInBackgroundWithId' with an argument list of type" for the following line of code: query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("parse id is placed in here")

Comment: @Blanco Paste the whole query function so we can take a look at it from A to B.

Comment: I believe I solved it but I am new to swift so if anyone else has a take on this I would like to know. I want to learn as much as I can about it.

Comment: @Blanco That looks very much like, if not identical to, the solution I proposed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "objectForKey:" method instead:

```
self.Question = objectHolder.objectForKey("Question") as! String
```